# I'm making a simple image classification model to detect if the image has a cat or not

Tags: python, numpy

this is the part of the code where I get the problem

```
# Load the image using PIL
image_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/_b3169321-61c1-4116-be9f-b1a4878318b5.jpg'
image = Image.open(image_path)

# Convert the image to a NumPy array
new_image = np.array(image)

# Preprocess the new image
new_image = new_image.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3) / 255.0
```

this is the error message

```
----> 9 new_image = new_image.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3) / 255.0

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3145728 into shape (224,224,3)
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: I noticed you are using -1 as a dimension in your numpy array. Maybe that should just be a 1?

Comment: Also, are you trying to normalize your rgb values by divind them by 255?

Comment: are you making a fancy **Cat on keyboard** detector

Comment: 224*224*3 equals 150528  but your array has 3145728 elements

Answer (score 1):

You are working with an image that has more pixels than the model input (224 x 224 x 3)

As you are using PIL, you can resize the image to that resolution with `PIL.Image.resize`

`image = Image.open(image_path).resize((224,224))`

This image now can be converted into a numpy array of shape `(224, 224, 3)` but if the original image has a different aspect ratio than 1:1, the image will be stretch into that aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

**The Solution :**

```
# Load the image using PIL
image_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/_b3169321-61c1-4116-be9f-b1a4878318b5.jpg'
image = Image.open(image_path)
image = image.resize((224,224)) #new line 
# Convert the image to a NumPy array
new_image = np.array(image)

# Preprocess the new image
new_image = new_image.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3) / 255.0
```

**Explanation :**

Ok, the issue is that your loaded image is not a 224 by 224 image, notice that in the error it says

***ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3145728 into shape (224,224,3)***

the size of an array is all the numbers in its shape multiplied together, so if you image's shape is (224,224,3) then its size will be 224x224x3 which is 150528,not 3145728. which means that the jpg image is bigger than (224,224,3), i did the calculation, to get a size of 3145728 your images shape has to be (1024,1024,3) so, basically you cant resize a (1024,1024,3) image to a (224,224,3), that will mean, throwing away some of the pixels and numpy won't do that for you, so maybe find images that are already 224,224,3 or reshape your image down to 224,224,3. So i added a "resize" to your code.

let me know if it worked